# Is the Ruined City an actual area in WOW?

Tags: world-of-warcraft, hearthstone

The last hearthstone adventure explores Orsis , Uldaman and the so called Ruined city. I know the first two do exist in WOW but what about the last one?

Comment: "Ruined City" is such a generic name.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The Ruined City seems to be a reference to the Sunken City of Vashj'ir in World of Warcraft.

This is supported both by all the enemies being water based and one of the Hearthstone bosses being [Lady Naz'jar](http://www.wowhead.com/npc=40586/lady-nazjar), who is one of the bosses of the [Throne of Tides](http://wow.gamepedia.com/Throne_of_the_Tides) dungeon in WoW's Vashj'ir zone.